# TinyMCE edit handler class

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tinymce

Does anyone know if TinyMCE has a special "edit" css class that can be applied to div elements whose sole purpose is to be applied within the editor visual mode?

I need to wrap my shortcode elements in divs with named classes that I can code against in order to improve formatting and usability within the content editor (similar to the way WordPress does with the "Gallery" and "Image" tags).

In other words, a div class I can use as a wrapper that, when the user clicks over to the text/html view, the div is removed from the markup. But when the user is in visual mode, I can use this div's class to apply custom css and javascript against the element.

I thought I had something going using the mceItem class, but I can no longer get it to work.

```
<div class="mceItem">
This div is only used for edit controls and TinyMCE handles it
differently than other divs within the editor?
</div>
```

I do realize I'll probably have to hook into the TinyMCE plugin architecture to do anything complicated, but just wanted to check if there's a shortcut for simple visual formatting hooks with a temporary "runtime style" div element.